# Error trying to loop through Linq query results

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need to pull any amount of records that correspond to a specific value (`CourseCode`), and insert these records into another table. This code works fine as long as the `Linq` code returns only one record, however if there is any more than that I get the following message:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. 
>   The existing object is in the Modified state.  An object can only be
>   added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added.

Below is my code:

```
            if (_db == null) _db = new AgentResourcesEntities();

            var prodCodes = from records in _db.CourseToProduct
                              where records.CourseCode == course.CourseCode
                              select records;

            foreach (var pt in prodCodes.ToList())
            {
                agentProdTraining.SymNumber = symNumber;
                agentProdTraining.CourseCode = course.CourseCode;
                agentProdTraining.ProductCode = pt.ProductCode;
                agentProdTraining.DateTaken = course.DateTaken;
                agentProdTraining.Method = course.Method;
                agentProdTraining.LastChangeOperator = requestor;
                agentProdTraining.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
                agentProdTraining.DateExpired = course.ExpirationDate;
                agentProdTraining.ProductCode = pt.ProductCode;
                agentProdTraining.NoteId = pt.NoteId;

                _db.AgentProductTraining.AddObject(agentProdTraining);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                PtAdded++;

                EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, "Product Training added", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is re-adding the same agentProdTraining object even though property values are changed. Create a new instance for each loop execution.

```
foreach (var pt in prodCodes.ToList())
{
  var agentProdTraining = new AgentProductTraining();

  agentProdTraining.SymNumber = symNumber;
  agentProdTraining.CourseCode = course.CourseCode;
  agentProdTraining.ProductCode = pt.ProductCode;
  agentProdTraining.DateTaken = course.DateTaken;
  agentProdTraining.Method = course.Method;
  agentProdTraining.LastChangeOperator = requestor;
  agentProdTraining.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
  agentProdTraining.DateExpired = course.ExpirationDate;
  agentProdTraining.ProductCode = pt.ProductCode;
  agentProdTraining.NoteId = pt.NoteId;

  _db.AgentProductTraining.AddObject(agentProdTraining);
  _db.SaveChanges();

  PtAdded++;

  EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, "Product Training added", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
}
```